# The project name changed after import in Android

Tags: android

When I import Android project, I find a problem that the project name is not the same as the original one. Like the project name is ExtendScreenWrap. After import project the name change to packagename + activity. So the build project matched well in java build path should match again after import. How could I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can Simply rename your project name,which won't affect in execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have missed something while importing. Just [check this link](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-importproject.htm) to see how to import existing projects.

Comment: @LiChe please up vote if the answer helps you. And also don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Think you are new to the community.

Answer (score 2):

Use this procedure:

1. File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace, Next
2. Select root directory: /path/to/project
3. Projects->Select All
4. UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to
   working sets"
5. Finish

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse

Click File -> Import ->General->Existing Project into Workspace.
Then select your root directory and press finish